# How to select database with dot in its name with laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, database

i have a project to show database value...
but, the database name has dot in it.
my database name is "t.produk".

How can i select the database in laravel?
i run it and got an error says it invalid like below

[image]

**EDIT:**
and i also did it with just string, came out error too :
[Here the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6sIW.png)

Comment: Not to be condescending, but naming conventions exist for a reason. this is not the only place you will run into issues with a name like that.

Comment: It looks like you surrounded the table name with backticks. Since it's a PHP string, shouldn't you use quotes?

Comment: Do you guys mind to look at the edit i just did?. it came out error too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all - avoid naming database tables like that. You should not use any dots there. It could be **t_produk** as example.

But table name should be descriptive so go for something like **products**. Than name your entity as Product.

You get this error here because you can't set variable as **(**`t.produk`**)**. You should pass a string as I see here. So do it like this:

```
protected $table = 't.produk';
```

EDIT:

I saw the error with a string variable. So now you see why the current table naming you choose is quite not good. DB reads it as follows:

select from database **t** table **produk**

If you will name your table like **t_produk** problem should be no longer here.

Comment: I know i can't use dot when naming tables. but the requirements for my test is i have to use dot in the name of the table. and has to be exact t.produk.

btw, i did what you do. it came out SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 't.produk' doesn't exist

Comment: Maybe in your test **t** stands for DB name and **produk** is for table name?

Comment: oh wait, they cut the tutorial video. at first they use t.produk, and cut it then it changed to tabel_produk.

Comment: I'm guessing "t" stands for "table" and "produk" (according to Google Transalte) is Indonesian for "product", so except for the dot, there's nothing wrong with that table name.

Comment: @kmoser sure, I know about it but it is generally good practice to use english names there. Ofc. you can put there word from any language and it will be ok as long as your whole team is from your country only.

Answer (score 0):

My bad, so the tables name can't have dot in it. noted.
Btw y'all thanks for the answers :)

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.  And it is repeating the information from another answer.